# Whats the new command that replaces `compass -w`?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I am trying to install https://github.com/markyoung/silk-sass-mixin

```
$ (sudo) gem install compass
$ git clone http://github.com/zarzax/silk-sass-mixin.git
$ cd silk-sass-mixin
$ compass -w
```

I get

> `D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\silk-sass-mixin>compass
>   -w WARNING: This interface is deprecated. Please use the new
>   subcommand interface. See`compass
>   help`for more information.`

Whats the new command then?

Comment: Did you see the help as exactly instructed in the output?

Comment: @Sarwar Erfan, yes, I got a list of commands which one do I use? I am a beginner at SASS/Compass, I don't even know what `-w` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-w watches a project for changes and recompile when a change is occurred.

The new command command for watch is:

```
compass watch [path/to/project] [path/to/project/src/file.sass ...] [options]
```

In the way you are using (as you are going to the project directory using `cd silk-sass-mixin`, you need to use

```
compass watch
```

Instead of

```
compass -w
```

Comment: ic, I was thinking it was to install the "plugin"